# select query for json in sql

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

I have below json in sql:

```
declare @jObject as nvarchar(max)='{
    "StudentData": [
        {
            "StudentID":5000,
            "StudentName":"xyz"

        },
        {
            "StudentID":5001,
            "StudentName":"abc"

        }
        ]

}'
```

I want to write select query such that :-

```
StudentID  StudentName
5000        xyz
5001        abc
```

I tried below query :-

```
SELECT *  
FROM OPENJSON(@jObject) 
WITH (StudentID int '$.StudentID',StudentName varchar(50) '$.StudentName')
```

But this is returning me single row and null values for both columns.
Please help.

Also tried below which is not working :-

**EDIT 1 :-**

```
SELECT *  
FROM OPENJSON(@jObject) 
WITH (StudentID int '$.StudentData.StudentID',StudentName varchar(50) '$.StudentData.StudentName')
```

Comment: You have an object with a *StudentData* property which contains objects with `StudentID`, ` StudentName` properties. Try `'$.StudentData.StudentID'`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos not working.. please see Edit1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your JSON string contains an object with a StudentData property which contains an array of objects with StudentID, StudentName properties. You need to query the contents of the `StudentData` property, not the root object.

To do that, pass the property's path to OPENSJON :

```
SELECT *  
FROM OPENJSON(@jObject,'$.StudentData') 
WITH (
    StudentID int '$.StudentID',
    StudentName varchar(50) '$.StudentName')
```

The result is :

```
StudentID   StudentName
5000        xyz
5001        abc
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing answer and your valuable time :)

Answer (score 0):

Note :- Answer suggested by @Panagiotis Kanavos worked 100%

I tried below query by myself and it also worked :-

```
SELECT    StudentID ,StudentName 
FROM OPENJSON(@jObject) 
WITH (StudentData nvarchar(max) AS JSON)
CROSS APPLY 
            OPENJSON (StudentData)
            WITH ( StudentName nvarchar(max), StudentID int)
```

Comment: You are parsing the object twice in this case